# powershell.exe -command get-clipboard modifies my terminal font if redirected

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running bash on ubuntu on wsl2.   I can run

```
powershell.exe -command get-clipboard
```

to output the contents of the clipboard.  That runs great. However, if I try to redirect the output at all, e.g.:

```
powershell.exe -command get-clipboard | cat
foo=$(powershell.exe -command get-clipboard)
powershell.exe -command get-clipboard > /dev/null
foo=`powershell.exe -command get-clipboard`
```

it changes the font of my whole terminal to 8x12 RasterFont.  And I have to change it back to Consolas.  What's going on? How do I capture the contents of the clipboard without modifying the font of my terminal.

Comment: Very interesting.  However, probably not on topic for Stack Overflow.  Could I recommend that you repost it over on [Super User](https://superuser.com)?  Also, would be useful to include which terminal you are using (Windows Terminal or something else?) in the question when you do.

Comment: There's another user asking almost exactly the same thing in [this post](https://superuser.com/q/1617959/1210833).  Let's see if we can come up with the answer there.

Comment: I think your issue is related to [microsoft/terminal issue #367](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/367), which was marked as a dupe of [microsoft/terminal issue #280](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/280).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with [older versions](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/280#issuecomment-517870239) of Windows PowerShell:

> There is a check in Windows PowerShell to see if the code page is supported by the Consolas font. The list is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/consolas). UTF-8 65001 isn't in that list, so whenever Windows PowerShell identifies a code page that isn't supported by Consolas, it will change the font to Terminal. PowerShell Core 6.x doesn't have this code anymore so you don't see this behavior.

You need to [download and install a newer version of PowerShell Core (6 or later)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell) and rewrite your command to use `pwsh.exe` (which points to the newer PowerShell Core 6-or-later) instead of `powershell.exe` (which points to the older Windows PowerShell 5.1) like so:

```
pwsh.exe -command get-clipboard
```